# how do I disable preview autosave?

Tags: preview

Today I was scrolling through my photography gallery with Preview app. I was playing around with files rotating them etc, only to discover that it was actually saving those files (overwriting originals) without giving me a notice!

Is there any way to make it ask me for changes everytime? not only when file is locked...

Comment: Preview only used to rewrite the EXIF tag to indicate the rotation, but left the image data itself intact. So if you rotated it back again in Preview, you'd get the original image back at its original quality. Is this no longer the case?

Comment: (Which doesn't help anyway if you'd also cropped them or edited them some other way, of course...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Lion?  If you are, you can check your versions by clicking the file title on the top of the window, then select Browser all Versions to revert back to the previous save.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might provide a decent solution: [How to Install the Older Preview App from Snow Leopard in Mac OS X Lion](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/27/how-to-install-the-older-preview-app-from-snow-leopard-in-mac-os-x-lion/).